# CSS is ignored in EmberJS handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

Have a problem with formatting table for **EmberJS**.
Clear table is nice with all necessary **CSS** formatting, but when I add

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars"></script>
```

for **Ember** output formatting seems to be ignored.

Also, inside those script-tags **JS** and **jQuery** selectors don't work neither.

Why this can happened? And how to make it work as needed?
Source here: [source at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/257/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to place your `mainDiv` *inside* the `<script>` tags. Otherwise since ember generates by default a `div` for it's generated view's you get an additional div nesting an thus your css styles are not applied correctly.

I've just changed this in the jsfiddle, you provided and it seams to work, at least the css styles are applied, [see here.](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/258/)

Hope it helps

**Edit:** see here your modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/PkT8x/260/) mentioned in the comments on how to handle events with ember.

Comment: Yeah, it makes easier for css, but jquery can't select items now, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/259/)

Comment: well, since you are using `ember.js` you should let it also handle events for you instead of using the plain jQuery syntax...

Comment: I've edited my answer, please have a look on how to handle events with ember instead of with plain jQuery

Comment: Great! It works as needed. And one more question, I can add classes, for example, using native JS or can use jquery methods inside Ember events?

Comment: And another question appeared...how can I find current item, would it be a button or a row in a table, I was trying "this" and "$(this)" in your scenario, but it returned "undefined" all the time.

Comment: how to add classes to your view please see here: http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/

Comment: and to your last question, I guess you should setup your app more the ember-way to have a good starting point on how to do things like "getting the current item" because all possible solution I could propose you continuing the example would be somewhat hackisch... :)

Comment: for this moment even hackisch solutions would be appliable. For now, I just want the working logic, then will study further. Here I need to select rows and have a chance to delete selected. Anyway thanks a lot.